# Output of one user with two roles

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I have two entities `User` and `Role`. They have a unidirectional `ManyToMany` connection. But when calling the list of Users, for some reason the User is returned several times with several roles.

Below I have provided the code and the result.

> Result

[image: new pic]

> Дебаг

[image: new pic]

> Code with HQL queries

```
 public List<User> listUsers() {
     List resultList = manager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles").getResultList();
     return resultList;
 }
```

UPD:

I found this solution:

```
public List<User> listUsers() {
    List resultList = manager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles")
            .unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

But the `criteria API` is slow, it is not recommended to use it, and it is deprecated.

**How do I display one user with two roles???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add a `distinct` statement in your query to avoid multiple entries

```java
 public List<User> listUsers() {
     List resultList = manager.createQuery("SELECT distinct u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles").getResultList();
     return resultList;
 }
```